# Paginator set always at the first page primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, paginator, primeng-table, p-table

The user, after a research that loads values in table,  can use pagination to show the other pages with the other value. The problem is that the user see paginator at the end of table but when click to go at the next page the values aren't update. This is my html

```
<p-table [value]="list"  role="table" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} di {totalPages})"
```

The pagination is set at the first page and It's not update when the user click the arrow to go next page.

So I  add this (`onPage`)

```
<p-table [value]="list" (onPage)="paginate($event)" role="table" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} di {totalPages})":
```

in ts

```
  paginate(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

the `console.log(event)` is never called so the method `paginate` is never called. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Can you create a StackBlitz to reproduce the problem please?